# Mathematical news sources.

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, education

I'm studying my high school right now but I really like math and it would be great for me if I could find a place where I can find about what is going on in the math world nowadays. About a year ago I was subscribed to the scientific american magazine and one time they put an article in there about Terrence Tao http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2012arXiv1201.6656T finding this proof to a weak version of the Goldbach conjecture.

Any good places where I can get a grasp of current mathematical research and what is being done right now? I know about papers and journals but I would like to get a wider picture without needing to be an expert in every field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an extensive mathblog circuit. While some blogs maintain a high level of rigor, I'd say that most intermix deep math, general thoughts and ramblings, and recent events of interest.

I'd like to recommend 4:

1. Firstly, the conglomerator [mathblogging.org](http://www.mathblogging.org/) is a big compendium of bloggers that is somewhat differentiated based on the skill level and content.
2. Secondly, I recommend Terry Tao's [blog](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/), although much of the time, Terry talks about his own research which will probably fly above most audiences.
3. I also recommend [Timothy Gower's blog](http://gowers.wordpress.com/), which tends to be almost entirely math news.
4. If you'll forgive the self-plugging, I also think [my blog](https://mixedmath.wordpress.com/) is pretty approachable, and I try to talk about things of interest to the greater math community some times.

Also, perhaps surprisingly, many mathematicians are very active of GooglePlus. Really, I'm serious.

Comment: Anyone know of any good optimization blogs?

Comment: "Really, someone actually uses GooglePlus, I swear!" :P

Answer (score 2):

The *notes* in [American Mathematical Monthly](http://www.maa.org/pubs/monthly.html) don't generally require PhD level expertise (though many of the *articles* do).  They aren't always about current events, but it could be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

i offer you  see following blog

> 1.[Mathematical Institutions and Centers](http://www.mathontheweb.org/mathweb/mi-inst.html)
>
> 2.[Electronic Newsgroups and Listservs](http://archives.math.utk.edu/news.html)
>
> 3.[MathDB Forum](https://newinfo-access.net/b/http://www.mathdb.org/phpBB3/viewforum.php?f=10)
>
> 4.[Sage in the news, blogs, forums and buzz sites](http://wiki.sagemath.org/SAGE_in_the_News)

Answer (score 1):

Less of a "news" kind of answer, but I very much recommend casually reading [the Princeton Companion To Mathematics](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8350.html). It helps bring you up to speed by giving a broad overview of various topics.